# How to use google-closure-compiler-js for a node.js app without gulp/grunt/webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler

The [docs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-js) don't have any examples of using this on its own but they do say this:

> Unless you're using the Gulp or Webpack plugins, you'll need to specify code via flags. Both jsCode and externs accept an array containing objects in the form {src, path, sourceMap}. Using path, you can construct a virtual filesystem for use with ES6 or CommonJS imports—although for CommonJS, be sure to set processCommonJsModules: true.

I've created a "compile.js" file based on the docs:

```
const compile = require('google-closure-compiler-js').compile;
const flags = {
  jsCode: [{path: './server/server.js'}],
  processCommonJsModules: true
};
const out = compile(flags);
console.info(out.compiledCode);
```

In my "./server/server.js" file, I put a `console.log` but it doesn't output. Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: What does your console.info output?

Comment: I get no output at all. When I use the flag `jsCode: [{src: 'const x = 1 + 2;'}]`, I get "var x=3;".

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [icidasset/quotes](https://github.com/icidasset/quotes/blob/be0de57f9f60c800dd09f9122f1c5f7ce031f4d6/config/functions/minify.js).

It appears, to me, that path is not intended to be used as you are using it.

Quote:

> Using `path`, you can construct a virtual filesystem for use with ES6 or CommonJS imports—although for CommonJS, be sure to set `processCommonJsModules: true`.

So instead you must expand your own sources, something webpack and gulp must be doing for you when you go that route.

```
files=['./server/server.js']
files.map(f => {
    const out = compile({
      jsCode: [{ src: f.content }],
      assumeFunctionWrapper: true,
      languageIn: 'ECMASCRIPT5'
    });
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got something to work, but it's not detecting any type errors or unused variables. It's simply outputting uglified code. `fs.readFile('./server/server.js', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  const flags = {
    jsCode: [{src: data}],
    assumeFunctionWrapper: true,
    languageIn: 'ECMASCRIPT6'
  };
  const out = compile(flags);
  console.info(out.compiledCode);
});`

Comment: This must be the right answer.  One use of the 'path' key in the JSON records accepted by 'jsCode', is for error/warning reporting.  For example, 
    compile({
             jsCode: [ {src: file.content, path: file.path} ]  })
returns a JSON object containing 'errors' and 'warnings' keys.  Each of them has a 'file' key that will reference the specified path in the example above.  If the path is not specified, a less user friendly default value will be used for the 'file' value instead.