# google-closure-compiler-js multiple module compiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler

I am compiling a couple of files by using google-closure-compiler-js on node.js;

I had some misunderstandings about how to compile multiply files via JavaScript code by using the node module... so I found this:

[How to use google-closure-compiler-js for a node.js app without gulp/grunt/webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925364/how-to-u)

but they are suggesting to compile all the files separately... which is problematic to do, when I have a few modules using each other.

The final question is:
how can I compile multiple modules via google-closure-compiler-js JavaScript API

I successfully do that by using google-closure-compiler-js command:

[image]

But when I use the solution suggested in another StackOverFlow question (the link is above ),I get these errors:

[image]

here are all my .js files:

build.js

```
const compile = require('google-closure-compiler-js').compile;
const fs = require('fs');


var files=['./js/math.js','./js/add.js'];


const out = files.map(f => {
  const out = compile({
  
    jsCode: [{ src: fs.readFileSync(f,'utf8') }],
    languageIn: 'ECMASCRIPT6',
    compilationLevel:'WHITESPACE_ONLY',

  });

  if(out.errors.length) console.info('ERRORs --- ',out.errors,'-----')

  return out;
});


console.info(out);
```

/js/math.js

```
import {add} from "./add.js"

console.info(add(1,2));
```

/js/add.js

```
export function add(a,b){

   return a+b;

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the compiled code in the browser? If so, this seems like an ideal task for Webpack. Is using Webpack an option?

Comment: @JackZelig The code is actually going to be run in browser .But I am not considering Webpack, at least I was not . Anyway at first I want to get clearer with the closure compiler (including because I am going to use closure library)

Comment: The problem is that browser support for ES6 modules is currently very poor. It seems to me that you need a tool to compile your ES6 into ES5 and bundle the various modules into one file which you can include in a web page. I don't think you can do this with the closure compiler, but with Webpack it would be simple. If you would like me to post an answer demonstrating how to do this with Webpack, just let me know.

Comment: @JackZelig Thank you , but the priority is ccjs .By the way , you can input ES6 code to ccjs and get ES5 code as output (with all the optimizations)

Comment: Yeah, sure you can have it transpile ES6 to ES5, you just can't (AFAIK) have it bundle modules for consumption in the browser. Would you consider using closure-compiler-js together with webpack?

Comment: @JackZelig Of course you can get a single .js file containing all the modules you give as input .( Wich is 'bundleing' , as I understood ). I even made it in the little example above ( by using ccjs from  command line:... math.js add.js > out.js  ) . The main problem is I can't  figure out how to do that by using js API .( Wich seems to be IS possible ) .And  transpileing , bundleing , optimazing  the code is happening the same time (during the compilation) , so I can't find any reason to use webpack , or even ccjs with webpack . Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Ok. Good luck. Sorry I couldn't help more.